# How to limit checkbox selectable checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Here is the code that I have compiled how ever it doesnt work.I am trying to limit selectable checkboxes with 2.

and here is the javascript code

```
 var limit = 2;
    $('input.civicrm-enabled.form-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
       if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
           this.checked = false;
       }
    });
```

Here is the html

https://codepaste.net/dp68y1

Comment: Is [this](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/forms/article.php/3479181) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the checkboxes aren't direct siblings.  An easy way to correct this issue would be to just use a `name` attribute selector.  See working example below.

```js
var limit = 2;
$("[name^='submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486]']").on('change', function(evt) {
   if($("[name^='submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486]']:checked").length > limit) {
       this.checked = false;
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-checkboxes webform-component--civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486">
  <label for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486">Which......?</label>
  <div class="form-checkboxes civicrm-enabled" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486">
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-1">
      <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-1" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][1]" type="checkbox" value="1"> <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-1">F</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-2">
      <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-2" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][2]" type="checkbox" value="2"> <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-2">A</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-3">
      <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-3" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][3]" type="checkbox" value="3"> <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-3">B</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-4">
      <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-4" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][4]" type="checkbox" value="4"> <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-4">T</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-5">
      <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-5" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][5]" type="checkbox" value="5"> <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-5">L</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-6">
      <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-6" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][6]" type="checkbox" value="6"> <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-6">W</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-7">
      <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-7" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][7]" type="checkbox" value="7"> <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-7">R</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-8">
      <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-8" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][8]" type="checkbox" value="8"> <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-8">B</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-9">
      <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-9" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][9]" type="checkbox" value="9"> <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-9">H</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-10">
      <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-10" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][10]" type="checkbox" value="10"> <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-10">I</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-11">
      <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-11" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][11]" type="checkbox" value="11"> <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-11">a</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can not add something in to html.It comes automatically Is there a way to do it without adding this line?
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @allstar you don't need to add that line, that was just so I could use jquery in this snippet.  You already have jquery imported.  (The only change you need to make is to your javascript).

Comment: @allstar well that's because jsfiddle doesn't come pre-packaged with jquery unless you tell it to use jquery.  I assume in your original codebase you already have jquery imported, since you're using it in your problem description?

Comment: Ok sorry it was a letter mistake now it works but it effects also other checkboxes on the page .How can I do this with div id? to avoid other checkbox changes?

Comment: @allstar I updated the code to use a more specific query selector

Comment: it is id is different than others i tried so but didnt work.https://jsfiddle.net/77tz33t9/

Comment: @allstar here, I fixed your selector in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/77tz33t9/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function(){
    var max = 2;
    var checkboxes = jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]');
    
    checkboxes.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var set = checkboxes.filter('[name="'+ this.name +'"]')
        var current = set.filter(':checked').length;
        return current <= max;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Checkboxes for Cat 1 - Max of Three in Category -->
<input type="checkbox" value="Option 1" id="CAT_Custom_365571_0" name="CAT_Custom_365571" />Creative<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="Option 2" id="CAT_Custom_365571_1" name="CAT_Custom_365571" />Euphoric<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="Option 3" id="CAT_Custom_365571_2" name="CAT_Custom_365571" />Uplifted<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="Option 3" id="CAT_Custom_365571_3" name="CAT_Custom_365571" />Uplifted<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="Option 3" id="CAT_Custom_365571_4" name="CAT_Custom_365571" />Uplifted<br />
```

Comment: I can not add something in to html.It comes automatically Is there a way to do it without adding this line?
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

These checkboxes are not the siblings of each other.Instead you can check ow many are checked in a page like this

```js
var limit = 2;
    $('input.civicrm-enabled.form-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
       if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > limit) {
           this.checked = false;
       }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-item webform-component webform-component-checkboxes webform-component--civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486">
      <label for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486">Which......? </label>
     <div id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486" class="form-checkboxes civicrm-enabled"><div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-1">
     <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-1" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][1]" value="1" type="checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-1">F </label>
    
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-2">
     <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-2" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][2]" value="2" type="checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-2">A </label>
    
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-3">
     <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-3" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][3]" value="3" type="checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-3">B </label>
    
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-4">
     <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-4" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][4]" value="4" type="checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-4">T </label>
    
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-5">
     <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-5" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][5]" value="5" type="checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-5">L </label>
    
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-6">
     <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-6" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][6]" value="6" type="checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-6">W </label>
    
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-7">
     <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-7" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][7]" value="7" type="checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-7">R </label>
    
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-8">
     <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-8" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][8]" value="8" type="checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-8">B </label>
    
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-9">
     <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-9" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][9]" value="9" type="checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-9">H </label>
    
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-10">
     <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-10" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][10]" value="10" type="checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-10">I </label>
    
    </div>
    <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-11">
     <input class="civicrm-enabled form-checkbox" id="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-11" name="submitted[civicrm_1_contact_1_cg24_custom_486][11]" value="11" type="checkbox">  <label class="option" for="edit-submitted-civicrm-1-contact-1-cg24-custom-486-11">a </label>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I can not add something in to html.It comes automatically Is there a way to do it without adding this line?
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: You don't need to add that to your code. You already have it imported. I just added it for snippet

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
var limit = 2;
    $('input.civicrm-enabled.form-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
    debugger
       if($('input.civicrm-enabled.form-checkbox:checked').length > limit) {
           this.checked = false;
       }
    });
```